# Facebook Messenger bot - looking for simple NLP engine

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, nlp, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I need a very simple NLP engine that can do the following:

1. Tell if the user answered Yes or No (in any way - including variations)
2. Tell if the user has just said Hello (including all variations like Hi, hi, hey, helllooo, hey there, etc...)

Comment: Services are allowed or not here is a good one https://wit.ai/?

Comment: I am looking for something very simple, preferable a js library or so...

Comment: To capture these answers first you need to have something like a state machine. Capturing Yes-No and other phrases with same meaning can be done by a dictionary of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in NLP feature uses wit.ai, and is about as simple as it gets. When you enable it, it automatically includes an `nlp` object with every message.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/built-in-nlp